# ng-quill with SharePoint AddIn not working

Tags: sharepoint-addin, angularjs

I am trying to use ng-quill with SharePoint AddIn but it's giving me errors,

> SCRIPT5022: [Parchment] Invalid definition quill.js (244,9) SCRIPT256:
>   This command is not supported. quill.js (7451,3)

When I use the same in pre HTML page it's working but not with AddIn.

**Default.html**

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    This is page Title area
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <div ng-app="HelloWorldApp">
        <p id="message" ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
            <!-- The following content will be replaced with the user name when you run the app - see App.js -->
            initializing...
            {{Hello}}
        </p>

        <%--<ng-quill-editor 
                     ng-model="title" 
                     placeholder="override default placeholder">
        </ng-quill-editor>--%>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.1/quill.snow.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.1/quill.bubble.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.1/quill.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/ng-quill/ng-quill.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/AngularApp.js"></script>

</asp:Content>
```